# JSON empty string to null

Tags: c#, .net, json, null, json.net

An empty string is usually parsed to null in JSON but I have a request which contains:

```
"StreetValue":"",
```

In my class it is de-serialized as a decimal

```
public decimal StreetValue { get; set; }
```

But when I pass the empty string it is getting de-serialized as 0.00M instead of null. What am I missing?

My intent is for it to be de-serialized as 0 only if "0.00M" is passed else it should be null.

Comment: `decimal` is not nullable, you cannot assign `null` to `decimal`.

Answer (score 3):

Try marking your property as a nullable type (note the question mark):

```
public decimal? StreetValue { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because string is a reference type, whereas decimal is a value type, so it can't be assigned null; instead, your property will receive `default(decimal)`.

As Steve said, you can make your property nullable:

`decimal? Prop { get; set; }`

This will allow you to use null as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your property to `dynamic` so you no need to declare data type and not to worry about `null` value.

```
public dynamic StreetValue { get; set; }
```

Edit:

In c# 6.0 property initialization will be available:

```
public decimal StreetValue { get; set; } = 0.0;
```

Comment: This means you lose the type of the property so is not very useful.

Comment: @Steve Have you use before that ?

Comment: @GilliVilla if you not get value in this property as my answer you get `null or empty string` when you de-serialized